# Call block in IOS 7.0 + Private API

Tags: ios7, iphone-privateapi, callblocking

How can we block call from iphone ( > IOS 7.0), through programmatically. Any private API.

Comment: Do you mean block a phone call?

Comment: BTW. If you are talking about a phone call, what type of call do you want to block (outgoing or incoming)?

Comment: I want to block both call, but first priority is incoming call.